# Run python Script as root

Tags: python

I have a python Script when i run my script by using my account it's run without problem [image],
But when i use the root account i have an issue like this[image]
I don't know why i have a problem with import module

Comment: You installed those packages for `root` user and not the `robot` user, so it can't find it. Install those either system wide for the `robot` user, if you wanna run that with `robot` user

Comment: The install is different for each user, so you'll need to install the packages as `robot`

Comment: A general note - You should cut/paste relevant code rather than posting images. Cf https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 0):

use an absolute python path to point to the version of python that has the right packages installed. 
The command `which python` executed as the user where the script works should help.

If you used `pip` to install any package locally, then you might have to
ensure as well, that the environment variable `$HOME` points to /home/robot.

In general I'd recommend to create a `virtualenv` foe your specific python project and use it in the sudo call explicitely or if you refer change the `#!` line in your script to point to the right virtualenv,